# Change xdebug.mode using Xdebug helper

Tags: xdebug

I have Xdebug helper for Chrome installed and I would like to switch between "off", "debug" and "profile"

Is it possible?

I'm using `Xdebug 3`

The Xdebug helper sets the following cookies

`XDEBUG_SESSION=...` when it's set to debug

`XDEBUG_PROFILE=...` when it's set to profile

Removes any `XDEBUG` cookies when it's set to disabled

How to change the mode based on the presence of these cookies?

Comment: Hi. I found this question via Google search for the same thing? Did you ever get anywhere with this? 

It seems really odd to me that the helper would have those four options to choose from, but it only uses the default xdebug.mode setting in php.ini. Surely that's what those four buttons are for?

Comment: @Aaryn Yeah, quite strange. The helper is more compatible with xdebug2. For xdebug3, the mode is loaded on startup and can't be changed without a restart. This can be solved using docker where you have multiple php fpm containers with each a different xdebug mode but it's overkill for this simple issue. Here if you are curious https://dev.to/unlocomqx/faster-dev-server-with-xdebug-3833

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @unloco :)